# mongodb nested schema - How to query a dynamic key

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have the following document structure,

```
    {
  "_id": "site1",
  "loc_layout": [
    {
      "dynamic_key1": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              80.05204336806904,
              13.131032427538385
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "site": "site1",
            "type": "gate",
            "location": "sgate1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "dynamic_key2": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              80.05204336804904,
              13.13103242754358
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "site": "site1",
            "type": "gate",
            "location": "sgate2"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              80.05204336807904,
              13.13103242753985
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "site": "site1",
            "type": "gate",
            "location": "sgate3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Above "dynamic_key1" & "dynamic_key2" are the dynamic key attributes. How to use this dynamic key to retrieve the required objects as an array.

I have tried with the below query,

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$loc_layout"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "site1",
      "loc_layout.dynamic_key1.properties.location": "sgate1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "loc_layout": 1
    }
  }
])
```

The expected result is,

```
{
  "_id": "site1",
  "location_layout": [
    {
      "dynamic_key1": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              80.05204336806904,
              13.131032427538385
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "site": "site1",
            "type": "gate",
            "location": "sgate1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Its a key whose value is not known @Takis_

Comment: so the question is just to keep members that have `location": "sgate1"` ? without caring of the parent key name? I am comfused a bit , because you say that the key is unknown, yet you use it by its name in your query. I mean the `"dynamic_key1"`

Answer (score -1):

You only need to `$project` the right field at the end, and no need for an `$unwind` too, this query get the result you're aiming to:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "site1",
      "loc_layout.dynamic_key1.properties.location": "sgate1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "loc_layout.dynamic_key1": 1
    }
  }
])
```

You could have a look on attribute pattern btw as storing dynamic fields isn't a good practice when you need to filter on their content since you can create index on them